# Communication Module Automation Testing

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I developed a communication protocol module between two machine in our product. It is an explicit
protocol and it was not possible to use standart protocol like WCF or WebServices

There are two functionalities for this module:
1. Send notification from end point 1 to end point 2
2. Send Request from end point 1 to end point 2 and receive response from end point 2 in end point 1.

Before we are doing full integration tests between those two machines (the other side is written in C++)
I wrote a client console and server console to simulate manually the two main funcionalities over the local tcp in my localhost.

What is the best way to automate this test in the solution build process? I tries to use unit test framework but it didnt worked so well. When using unit tests framework i had to run the client and server in two different threads and it didnt go so fluently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a mocking framework such as [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) in your unit tests to allow you to simulate the connection to endpoint 2. This would allow you to test that endpoint 1 behaves properly to all of the possible types of response from endpoint 2. For example, you would assert that endpoint 1 throws an exception if it cannot connect to endpoint 2.